# Have any deep-space spacecraft supported same-band turnaround of Earth-based doppler measurements?

Tags: spacecraft, doppler-ranging, delay-doppler

Table 1 of [DSN Telecommunications Link Design Handbook, 201, Rev. B, Frequency and Channel Assignments](https://deepspace.jpl.nasa.gov/dsndocs/810-005/201/201B.pdf) gives Spacecraft Transponder Turnaround Ratios that are supported by the Deep Space Network. These are the PLL controlled divide-by ratios that a spacecraft uses when receiving a carrier frequency from the DSN and retransmitting a different frequency back to Earth which is still phase-coherent, for the purposes of precise doppler shift measurements as part of a determination of a (usually deep space) spacecraft's trajectory. Read more about this in [How does a three-way doppler shift measurement work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23336/12102).

Some of the supported ratios are within-band and close to unity; X to X-band, Ka to Ka-band and S to S-band. This means that the spacecraft must simultaneously receive a very weak signal and transmit a very strong signal at frequencies that are very close, and this requires more frequency rejection in the spacecraft's receive circuit.

**Question:** Are there any deep-space spacecraft which actually support within-band turn-around for Earth-based doppler measurements? Are these spacecraft using one dish for simultaneous receive and transmit within the same band?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and yes. The standard Doppler data type on deep-space spacecraft is X-band to X-band, and transmit and receive are on the same antenna. Most deep-space spacecraft only *have* X-band transceivers. A few have more than one band, usually for either radio science reasons and/or higher data rate on Ka (accepting some added risk of weather interference). S-band is passé.