# Exact speed/distance of JWST (& others in L1/L2 halo) from Earth; is it measured any differently than for more distant deep-space missions?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, james-webb-telescope, tracking, velocity, ground-station

How is the exact speed and distance from Earth of the JWST or any spacecraft in a Sun-Earth L1/L2 halo orbit determined?

While deep space missions require ranging at hundreds of millions of kilometers to billions, these spacecraft always remain less than 2 million kilometers from Earth.

Does this "relatively short" distance (on a deep space scale) lead to tracking strategies different than those used for much more distant missions?

Comment: same as for any distant probe. A bit of parallax, a lot of doppler and timing on the comms, some visual observation. Look around there will be many related Questions in here.

Comment: Welcome to Space Exploration Stack Exchange! I've made some adjustments to your question because as the previous comment mentions, the general techniques used for tracking deep space missions has been addressed in several other questions and answers. To make sure your question is new and somewhat different I've asked about any differences between the way JWST is tracked and the way far more distant missions are tracked. Feel free to edit further or roll back. To read more click the "tracking" tag under your questions. I'll add links to a few key answers in a few minutes.

Comment: Different but related: [How do we track the exact location of the spacecraft which is millions or billions of miles away from us?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21256/12102) and [How are precision trajectory measurements made of trans-Neptunian spacecraft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14681/12102) and [How does a three-way doppler shift measurement work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23336/12102) Also check out NASA's [What is the Deep Space Network?](https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/heo/scan/services/networks/deep_space_network/about)