# Has there ever been a non-negligible probability of conjunction between spacecrafts in Lunar orbit?

Tags: isro, collision-avoidance, conjunction, lro

Apparently ISRO's Chandrayaan-2 orbiter and NASA's LRO narrowly avoided a possible conjunction event in Lunar orbit due to timely assessment and action of both agencies.

https://www.isro.gov.in/update/15-nov-2021/chandrayaan-2-orbiter-ch2o-performs-evasive-manoeuvre-to-mitigate-critically

Is this first of its kind event or there have been other instances where possibility of collision between lunar orbiters was detected and avoided?

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for; Chandrayaan-1 [went incommunicado and therefore untracked for many years](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20582/12102), so while the probability of a conjunction with anything was low on average, it was also *completely unpredictable*

Comment: And there is now a predicted "conjunction" between [a spacecraft in cis-lunar space and the Moon itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e_5-T1#Third_stage_disposal)!

Comment: Besides Apollo (although those were planned).